# Draw on QTreeWidget With QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qtreewidget

I'm working on a little program and I have a bunch of panels in it. I want it so that when I focus into a panel, it draws a thin inline around it to show that it is focused. I got it working with all my panels except my tree view.

Here's an example that works with a `QWidget`:

```
void Test::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if(hasFocus())
    {
        QPainter painter(this);

        QPen pen(Qt::blue);
        pen.setWidth(1);
        painter.setPen(pen);

        painter.drawRect(geometry());

    }

    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```

When I use the `QPainter` on the `QTreeWidget` I get these debug messages in the console:

- `QWidget::paintEngine`: Should no longer be called
- `QPainter::begin`: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
- `QPainter::setPen`: Painter not active
- `QPainter::drawRects`: Painter not active

So my problem is that I can't use `QPainter` with the `QTreeWidget` so I am unable to draw my outline. Is there an alternative method I can use?

Comment: Why not use `paintEvent` in a `QTreeWidget`? You can call `QTreeWidget::paintEvent(event)` to perform the painting of the superclass

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. I always call the superclass in the paint event, I did however forget to add it to the given example. But that's not my problem anyway. My problem is I need to draw a rect around the geometry of the QTreeWidget, which I cannot do with just by calling the superclass. I need like a QPainter or something...

Comment: Why can't you create a `QPainter` therefore? A `QTreeWidget` should be a subclass of `QWidget` ... and btw you should add `QWidget::paintEvent(event)` outside of the `if`

Comment: Try it and you'll see why. I don't know why it won't let me, but I get these messages in the debug output. I'll add them to the question

Comment: You can try to create your own widget and add the `QTreeWidget` to it, that should work, but I don't know if that's the best option

Comment: I thought of doing that but figured why not ask online about a way to do it directly in the QTreeWidget, so I wouldn't have to make a dedicated class for the QTreeWidget just so it can have its outline lol.

Comment: You need to draw a border after call of base `QTreeWidget::paintEvent`. Not before. Btw, content is drawing by viewport.

Comment: I did put it before in what I coded because I know `paintEvent` will paint the `QTreeWidget` stuff over anything I draw before it so I did the `paintEvent` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `paintEvent` at all. Use just stylesheet (`setStyleSheet()` method):

```
QTreeWidget:focus{ border: 1px solid red}
QTreeWidget:!focus{}
```

Result:

[image]